# Loading Velocity Templates from nested JARs

Tags: java, classpath, velocity, onejar

I have an application packaged inside of a onejar, which uses Velocity for templating.

In my maven project setup, I have a file in `$base/src/main/resources/template.html`.  When the app gets packaged as a onejar, the resulting onejar contains a nested jar inside of it (under main/my-jar.jar).   That jar in turn has that `template.html` file packaged under its root.  (Apparently maven copied it from src/main/resources into the root of the package)

I'd like to load that template as a resource in Velocity.  I've read I need to use a ClassPathResourceLoader to do that, so I have code that looks like this:

```
    VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
    ve.setApplicationAttribute("resource.loader", "class");

    ve.setApplicationAttribute("class.resource.loader.class", 
                               org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader.class);

    ve.init();
    Template t = ve.getTemplate("template.html");
```

This fails every time, with an exception that none of Velocity's resource loaders can find the file.

I have two questions - first, is this even the right way to configure the use of the ClasspathResourceLoader?   And second, if that were configured properly, what path would I specify so that template.html could be found inside of that inner nested jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the answer after a lot of digging.

The code to use the ClasspathResourceLoader is as follows:

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();

ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath"); 
ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

ve.init();
```

Secondly, many people are telling me that inside of a nested jar, the standard classpath loader shouldn't even be able to find the `template.html` file.  I was told that some fancy third party classloader would be necessary.   OneJar provides such a fancy loader.  Once I got the code correct to use the ClasspathResourceLoader, things seemed to resolve.

The thing to keep in mind is that "/" is relative to the classpath root.  So when `$base/src/main/resources/template.html` got repackaged as `template.html` in the root directory of the unpacked JAR, that meant that `/template.html` was the right resource path to load.

That path `/template.html` is of course relative to the nested inner JAR.  How the class loader (whether standard or OneJar) didn't get confused between the `/` of the outer jar and the inner jar, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

specify the path where your template.html resides using / as relative path

and use `setProperty` like below

```
VelocityEngine ve = new VelocityEngine();
            ve.setProperty(RuntimeConstants.RESOURCE_LOADER, "classpath");
            ve.setProperty("classpath.resource.loader.class", ClasspathResourceLoader.class.getName());

            ve.init();

            final String templatePath = "/" + template + ".html";


            Template template = ve.getTemplate(templatePath, "UTF-8");
```